# How can I include a navigation bar on my homepage in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I created a navigation menu from data of the mySQL database:

navbar.html.twig

```
      {% block body %}
      {% for page in pages %}
      {{page.name}}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endblock %}</span>
```

PageController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Pages;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/pages", name="pages")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $pages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findAll();
        return $this->render('inc/navbar.html.twig', array('pages' => $pages));
    }
}
```

If I open now `mypage.com/pages` it works fine. I see all my pages.
But I want to use the navigation menu now on my main page, so I included it.

homepage.html.twig:

```
{% block title %}Symfony{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{{ include('inc/navbar.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I open `mypage.com` I get the error:

> Variable "pages" does not exist.

Comment: You include your navbar on your homepage without giving the variable $pages with it.

Comment: @MrJ. But how do I do this?

Comment: What do u mean? Either pass `pages` or use the filter `default`, e.g. `{% for {% for page in pages|default([]) %`

Comment: @DarkBee Now I am confused

Comment: Scratch the first `{% for` - It should be `{% for page in pages|default([]) %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your variable 'Pages' to your homepage in the same way you give it to your /pages page. Add `array('pages' => $pages)` to your homepage function.

Or alternatively you can use @DarkBee's answer by putting `{% for page in pages|default([]) %}` in your navbar.html.twig. (Credits goes to @DarkBee)

Comment: So I really have to add this variable to every Controller for all my pages I want to use a navigation menu? This does not seem to me very convenient

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You could add it as a global variable or you could write a custom function which return the pages